# Compact way to map strings to datatype using Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I seem to be coming across mapping keywords straight to a datatype fairly often and I solve it as below. It can quickly get out of hand as you have to repeat the string values.

Is there a more compact way to express this?

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

data Keyword = Apple | Banana | Cantaloupe

parseKeyword :: Parser Keyword
parseKeyword = (  string "apple"
              <|> string "banana"
              <|> string "cantaloupe"
               ) >>= return . strToKeyword
                    where strToKeyword str = case str of
                           "apple"      -> Apple
                           "banana"     -> Banana
                           "cantaloupe" -> Cantaloupe
```

EDIT:

As a followup question, since this seemed to be too easy. How would the compact solution work with `try`?

E.g.

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

data Keyword = Apple | Apricot | Banana | Cantaloupe

parseKeyword :: Parser Keyword
parseKeyword = (  try (string "apple")
              <|> string "apricot"
              <|> string "banana"
              <|> string "cantaloupe"
               ) >>= return . strToKeyword
                    where strToKeyword str = case str of
                           "apple"      -> Apple
                           "apricot"    -> Apricot
                           "banana"     -> Banana
                           "cantaloupe" -> Cantaloupe
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m not sure this is a terribly elegant solution, but if you derive a few more typeclasses:

```
data Keyword = Apple | Banana | Cantaloupe deriving (Eq, Read, Show, Enum, Bounded)
```

You can suddenly get all of the values:

```
ghci> [minBound..maxBound] :: [Keyword]
[Apple,Banana,Cantaloupe]
```

For any particular value, we can parse it and then return the value:

```
parseEnumValue :: (Show a) => a -> Parser a
parseEnumValue val = string (map toLower $ show val) >> return val
```

Then we can combine these to parse any value of it:

```
parseEnum :: (Show a, Enum a, Bounded a) => Parser a
parseEnum = choice $ map parseEnumValue [minBound..maxBound]
```

Try it out:

```
ghci> parseTest (parseEnum :: Parser Keyword) "cantaloupe"
Cantaloupe
ghci> parseTest (parseEnum :: Parser Keyword) "orange"
parse error at (line 1, column 1):
unexpected "o"
expecting "apple", "banana" or "cantaloupe"
```

Comment: Definitely the most creative solution. Elegant, not so much.

Comment: I think I didn't read it properly at first. Looking it over it is actually fairly elegant.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to avoid some repetition, you could use the [`(<$)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--36-) operator:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Control.Applicative ((<$))

data Keyword = Apple | Banana | Cantaloupe

parseKeyword :: Parser Keyword
parseKeyword
    =   Apple      <$ string "apple"
    <|> Banana     <$ string "banana"
    <|> Cantaloupe <$ string "cantaloupe"
```

It's also possible to make a fully generic solution for any type that only has unit constructors using [`GHC.Generics`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.3/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.1/GHC-Generics.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Control.Applicative ((<*))
import Data.Char (toLower)
import GHC.Generics

class GParse f where
    gParse :: Parser (f a)

instance (GParse f, Constructor c) => GParse (C1 c f) where
    gParse = fmap M1 gParse <* string (map toLower $ conName (undefined :: t c f a))

instance GParse f => GParse (D1 c f) where
    gParse = fmap M1 gParse

instance (GParse a, GParse b) => GParse (a :+: b) where
    gParse = try (fmap L1 gParse) <|> fmap R1 gParse

instance GParse U1 where
    gParse = return U1

genericParser :: (Generic g, GParse (Rep g)) => Parser g
genericParser = fmap to gParse
```

That's quite a lot of boilerplate, but now you can create a parser for any compatible type with just:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

data Keyword = Apricot | Apple | Banana | Cantaloupe deriving (Show, Generic)

parseKeyword :: Parser Keyword
parseKeyword = genericParser
```

Testing in GHCI:

```
> parseTest parseKeyword "apple"
Apple
> parseTest parseKeyword "apricot"
Apricot
> parseTest parseKeyword "banana"
Banana
```

Handling multi-word constructors like `RedApple` is just a matter of writing the strings translation function for `"RedApple"` -> `"red_apple"` and using that in the `C1` instance. I.e.

```
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Data.Char (toLower, isLower)

mapName :: String -> String
mapName = intercalate "_" . splitCapWords where
    splitCapWords "" = []
    splitCapWords (x:xs) =
        let (word, rest) = span isLower xs
        in (toLower x : word) : splitCapWords rest

instance (GParse f, Constructor c) => GParse (C1 c f) where
    gParse = fmap M1 gParse <* string (mapName $ conName (undefined :: t c f a))
```

Comment: Interesting addition. A little over my head at this stage. Would that still be a good solution if you started getting more complicated keyword to data mappings e.g. "red_apple" -> "RedApple"?

Comment: Added an example of how to parse constructor names like `RedApple`.

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
parseKeyword
    =   (string "apple"      >> return Apple)
    <|> (string "banana"     >> return Banana)
    <|> (string "cantaloupe" >> return Cantaloupe)
```

---

For your follow up, this seems to work equally well as your implementation for the half dozen random tests I did

```
parseKeyword :: Parser Keyword
parseKeyword
    = try (string "apple"      >> return Apple)
    <|>   (string "apricot"    >> return Apricot)
    <|>   (string "banana"     >> return Banana)
    <|>   (string "cantaloupe" >> return Cantaloupe)
```

The technique is just making each subexpression return the final type instead of delegating it to the end of the block for a case statement.  The returns don't change the behavior of the parser.

Comment: I accepted shang's answer because he got in first but I will actuall use yours so I don't have to learn another operator just yet.

Comment: @kasbah Whichever you want to use is fine.  shang's solution is nice for its brevity, but it's up to you if you feel like using an alternate [`Functor` operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#Functor), which is defined simply as `fmap . const`, which may be easier to visualize by seeing `5 <$ Just 1 == Just 5`, `5 <$ Nothing == Nothing`.  Since `Parser` is a `Functor`, this works to basically replace the value inside the `Parser` container with what was specified on the `<` side of the operator.  This only occurs if the parse succeeded.